# Проблема работы кода в opere

Tags: ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте. Я недавно начал переписывать плеер для сайта-каталога. В хроме, Мозиле работает корректно и хорошо, но вот в опере почему-то не хочет видеть поток который подгружается.

Может кто поможет решить проблему или улучшить работу скрипта

Скрипт: http://pastebin.com/qkU4Wqmc

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f3c43767d241e6bb7fa4 так пойдет?

Comment: а чего-то изменилось?

Comment: не хочет работать в опере http://radiomaniya.ru можешь проверить